# How do I rename columns in tidyverse with vectors of names

Tags: r, dplyr, dynamic, rename

I wrote the following (working) function to change column names from vectors that contain both the current and desired column names,

```
change.name <- function (dt, from, to) 
{
    loc <- match(from, names(dt))
    chg.loc <- loc[!is.na(loc)]
    if (length(chg.loc) == 0) 
        return(dt)
    names(dt)[chg.loc] = to[!is.na(loc)]
    return(dt)
}
```

Is it possible to replace this function with rename or some other part of dplyr. I would  rather not need my own function.

Here is an example of the desired functionality,

```
cnames = tibble(from = c("hair_color", "banana", "height"),
                to = c("HeadCap", "Orange", "VertMetric"))
starwars %>% select(name, height, mass, hair_color, skin_color) %>% 
  top_n(5) %>% change.name(cnames$from, cnames$to)
```

> ```
>   name            VertMetric  mass HeadCap skin_color 
>   <chr>                <int> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>      
> 1 R2-D2                   96  32   NA      white, blue
> 2 R5-D4                   97  32   NA      white, red 
> 3 Gasgano                122  NA   none    white, blue
> 4 Luminara Unduli        170  56.2 black   yellow     
> 5 Barriss Offee          166  50   black   yellow
> ```

Note that "banana" in cnames$from is missing from starwars and doesn't trip up the function.

Comment: See my answer [here (73373657)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73372776/r-purrr-rename-columns-using-multiple-str-replace/73373657#73373657) for usage of rename_all() in conjunction with str_replace_all()

Comment: As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68968141/903061), you can use `rename(any_of(setNames(cnames$from, cnames$to)))`, though I do wish there was an interface that was more expressive, like in data.table you can do `setnames(data, old = from, new = to, skip_absent = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rename_with`, but in this implementation below, I still need to index `to` and `from` on the existing names

```
idx = cnames$from %in% names(starwars)

starwars %>% select(name, height, mass, hair_color, skin_color) %>% 
  top_n(5) %>% 
  rename_with(~cnames$to[idx], cnames$from[idx])
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68968141/903061), you can use

```
rename(any_of(setNames(cnames$from, cnames$to)))
```

(Note that I am not closing this question as a duplicate, as I think the table-structure of the names lookup is a common case and an important distinction.)

I do wish there was an interface that was more expressive, like in `data.table` you can do `setnames(data, old = from, new = to, skip_absent = TRUE)`. We could roll our own, but that defeats the purpose of "not needing my own function". But I would imitate `data.table`'s syntax:

```
rename_old_new = function(data, old, new, skip_absent = FALSE) {
  if(skip_absent) {
    rename(data, any_of(setNames(old, new)))
  } else {
    rename(data, all_of(setNames(old, new)))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One choice is to use `rename_with()` + `recode()` and pass a named vector for unquote splicing with `!!!`.

```r
starwars %>%
  select(name, height, mass, hair_color, skin_color) %>% 
  rename_with(~ recode(.x, !!!setNames(cnames$to, cnames$from)))

# # A tibble: 87 × 5
#    name               VertMetric  mass HeadCap       skin_color 
#    <chr>                   <int> <dbl> <chr>         <chr>      
#  1 Luke Skywalker            172    77 blond         fair       
#  2 C-3PO                     167    75 NA            gold       
#  3 R2-D2                      96    32 NA            white, blue
#  4 Darth Vader               202   136 none          white      
#  5 Leia Organa               150    49 brown         light
#  ...
```